# Is there a way to loop combined animations using animate.css? I am trying to bounce/slide in words and have them bounce out

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-animations

Basically I am trying to create a slideshow of text only using the bounceInLeft then bounceInRight using Dan Eden's animate.css : https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Instead of applying both classes to a tag, which doesn't work, I used the webkit animation to start the second animation 2 seconds later. This works but only goes through one time and I'd like to have it loop but with other words as well. I also tried adding the infinite class but it only repeats the last animation (bounceOutRight). Adding a third and fourth animation to the webkite-animation also does not seem to work.

I have very limited javascript knowledge and I'm assuming I just need to create an array of the words I want and have them loop through but I'm not sure how I would go about that. Any help would be appreciated!

```
.bounceInLeft {
-webkit-animation: bounceInLeft 1s, bounceOutRight 2s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is because you set the delay for the second animation to zero second... so it cannot complete... because he cannot start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a jquery plugin that does this
http://morphist.fyianlai.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.bounceInLeft {
-webkit-animation: bounceInLeft 1s infinite, bounceOutRight 2s infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 1.5s;
}
```

If you only add it on the last one, it will of course only repeat the last one.

Comment: Damn I was hoping it was that simple but it didn't work for me. It repeated bounceInLeft twice but then just repeated the second animation over and over.

Comment: I think it clashes between your delay and the infinite. Try checking out `@keyframe` and see if you can stage your animations through that, infinitely.